# iOS FCM push notifications blocking UI thread

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

How can I prevent application from freezing when I receive bunch of push notifications in short period of time. (I'm testing this by sending 1000 messages in for loop from node server). Application freezes until all messages are handled.

They are all just data notifications, no message part.

```
extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate {
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        print("Received Firebase token: \(fcmToken)")
    }

    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            print("Application recevied remote message.")
            let appData = remoteMessage.appData
            self.handleRemoteNotification(appData)
        }
    }

}
```

messaging didReceive is called on UI thread, and even if I don't do anything in it, it is still going to block UI thread.

Android handles it well, I can send 10k messages and it will still be responsive, messages will be late couple of minutes, but app will work fine.

Comment: What you are implemented in handleRemoteNotification method?

Comment: It updates some data on other places, but it doesn't matter, even if I leave messaging didReceive method empty or don't even override it, it will still freeze application.